# Shinyloadtest : Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : Timeout was reached: Connection timed out after 10004 milliseconds

Tags: r, curl

while running playback for shinyloadtest when I run below lines of code im getting error

```
library(rlang)
library(purrr)
library(ggplot2)
library(httr)
library(progress)
library(rsconnect)

poll(
servers = c('http://127.0.0.1:[port]'),
appName = 'myapp',
duration_sec = 180,
platform = 'ssp'
)
```

> ---------- Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) :    Timeout was reached: Connection timed out after 10004 milliseconds
>
> ---